# samba: files written to public share belong to nobody

Tags: linux, samba

I have setup a samba share like this:

```
    [shared]
    path = /home/shared/
    comment = shared
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
```

I can access it from windows, but when I upload files to it, the files I uploaded have the following permission:

```
-rwxr--r-- 1 nobody nobody 899381 Mar  7 11:59 letter17.rtf
```

What I would like to see is that, when a user accesses this share, the user acts as if he was a particular user of the samba server(say dave). So that he has access to files that 'dave' has access to, and the files he uploaded belongs to 'dave'.
which option do I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Samba global configuration you need to specify the guest mapping. It seems that on your installation this guest mapping is mapped to *nobody*.

Edit your `smb.conf` file and add something like the following in the `[Global]` section:

```
guest account = dave
```

Replace `dave` by whatever you want.

Comment: just tried it out. works like a charm. Thank you. :)